# Using Meteor Autoform 'meteormethod' attribute callbacks?

Tags: meteor, mandrill, meteor-autoform

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.ContactForm = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Your name",
    max: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
    label: "E-mail address"
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    label: "Message",
    max: 1000
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="contactForm">
  {{#autoForm schema=Schemas.ContactForm id="contactForm" type="method" meteormethod="sendEmail"}}
  <!-- etc. -->
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Meteor method, please check the comments:

```
Meteor.methods({

  sendEmail: function(contents){
    check(contents, Schemas.ContactForm);
    Mandrill.messages.send({
      // do something to send
    }, function(error, response){
      if (error){
        // how does error bubble back up to the client?
      } else {
        // how does success bubble back up to the client?
      }
    })
  },

})
```

So using the AutoForm `meteormethod` attribute, how do I get the error or the response from my server call to Mandrill to bubble back up to the client so that I can inform the user that the form has been submitted and emailed successfully?

Would it be better simply to not use the `meteormethod` attribute on AutoForm and wire up a `Meteor.call` on form submission manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.methods({

  sendEmail: function(contents){
          check(contents, Schemas.ContactForm);
          return Mandrill.messages.send({
          // do something to send
          }, function(error, response){
             if (error){
               return error
             } else {
               return response
             } 

  })},})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Meteor.wrapAsync` to call it and returning that.

```
return Meteor.wrapAsync(Mandrill.messages.send, Mandrill.messages)(contents);
```